# Why read-only memory mapped regions have dirty pages?

Tags: linux, memory-management

Executing (for example) the following command to get the list of memory mapped pages:

```
pmap -x `pidof bash`
```

I got this output:
[image]
Why some read-only pages are marked as "dirty", i.e. written that require a write-back? If they are read-only, the process should not be able to write to them... (In the provided example dirty pages are always 4 kB, but I found other cases with different values)

I checked also the /proc/*pid*/smaps and that pages are described as "Private Dirty".

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww actually in your link: " if your question generally covers… software tools commonly used by programmers … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!"

I think that it's something in the middle, but it's strongly related to development, so StackOverflow seems correct IMHO.

Comment: You missed the other half of that: *"... AND is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development"*.

Comment: @jww The question is strongly correlated with development on a particular platform, and seems to require a developer's experience to answer. (I doubt a non-developer (e.g. a [su]) would be able to provide a useful answer.)

Comment: @jpaugh - I rarely use Super User, so I can't really comment. I frequently use [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/), and you will certainly get high quality answers on U&L.SE. I'd wager you would get more than the 0 answers provided here. For what its worth, I don't think it was a bad question.

Comment: @jww I don't agree with you, please read the closing motivation "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow *unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming*". You say "0 answer here" but you have closed the question after less than 2 hours (meanwhile it got 3 upvotes and 3 stars, showing the interest of the community).

I will move the question to Unix & Linux but I'll continue to doubt that this is correct.

Comment: I join those who regard this as yet another case of overzealous zapping. I though this was an interesting question and vote to reopen.

Comment: IMHO, the process of allocating portions of virtual memory is a concept used for programming. I think the question should be reopened.

Comment: Just for the record, the question on Unix & Linux: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/402169/why-read-only-memory-mapped-regions-have-dirty-pages